# In Java, how to populate available tags based on cursor location in XML using DTD?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I am using XOM (or JDOM) to construct an XML editor. I am trying to allow user to avoid typing in XML code, but select available tags from a side-pane to insert tags/attributes into the XML code. The side pane will likely be generated from a set of DTD (or Schema) files.

Is there a module that can populate available tags/attributes based on DTD and currently selected node location?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache XMLSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/xmlschema20/) (e.g.) to wander around in a schema.

You can convert a DTD to an XML schema using trang.

To see more about how to use xml schema, I recommend reading the unit tests.

Consider for example [this one](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/xmlschema/tags/xmlschema-2.0/xmlschema-core/src/test/java/tests/ElementRefsTest.jav). Note the call to `schemaCol.getElementByQName(elementQName)` to find a particular element.

To visit all the elements, you'd start with `org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.getElements()` and iterate the map.

There are much meatier examples inside of Apache CXF.

Comment: Thanks, I am giving XMLSchema 2.0 a try.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to wander around the schema after getting an Schema, XmlSchemaElement or XmlSchemaForm... Do you mind also provide an example?

Comment: I was able to get subElements out of a parent Element after study the CXF source. Thanks for your help!